# PayPal приём платежей

Tags: php, paypal

Привет!
Просматривал много статей о том, как работать с пайпел, как принимать paypal на своём сайте. Итого вышло 2 способа:

1. Как у всех мерчантов. Создаётся форма action которой это сервис paypal и передаются поля по мимо прочих: cmd = _xclick и notify_url - ссылка на обработчик платежа после его оплаты.
2. Через API papypal. Используя методы: SetExpressCheckout, DoExpressCheckoutPayment, GetExpressCheckoutDetails. Первый метод создаёт счёт и возвращает токен, после чего мой скрипт должен сделать перенаправление на paypal страницу оплаты с ранее полученным токеном. После того как пользователь на paypal подтверждает оплату идёт запрос на мой скрипт с токеном и идентификатором плательщика. Скрипт вызывает метод DoExpressCheckoutPayment для завершения платежа и метод GetExpressCheckoutDetails для получения деталей.

Очевидно, что первый способ проще. Но почему так много статей со вторым способом? Их больше чем с более простым первым. Есть какие-то преимущества второго способа? Зачем вообще тогда его придумали

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно же - потому, что первый способ проще. А второй интересней, т.к. возможностей у него больше )

В первом случае вы описываете [кнопку "Buy Now"](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/singleitem-intro-outside). Она итак прекрасно описана на самом PayPal. Это самый простой способ предоставления пользователю возможности оплаты используя PayPal.

Во втором случае - одну из возможностей устаревшего Classic Api(на базе SOAP) - [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#ec). При желании, используя его можно сделать аналог кнопки "Buy Now".

Но на Express Checkout'ах возможности Classic Api не ограничиваются - их гораздо больше. Там есть есть и аунтификация пользователей, автоматические платежи и оплаты(как в Steam, например - когда по желанию пользователя можно оплачивать товары вообще без перехода на сайт PayPal, по нажатию всего одной кнопки; ну и всякие переодические платежи тоже используют это), выставление счетов, массовые платежи.

Достаточно давно PayPal ввела [новый API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) (использует REST) - там добавили ещё больше всяких интересных возможностей для бизнеса.

Comment: В общем понятно) Реализация кнопки "Buy Now" через API - близко к извращенству. Спасибо))