# Подключение PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Есть ли какойто легкий способ подключить PayPal систему пополнение счёта на сайте?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419379/paypal-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9